# Keras Captcha OCR - How to pass single jpeg image to loaded (trained) model and receive prediction in string?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, ocr, captcha

for the past several hours I was looking all over the internet for an answer to how I can pass a single jpeg image into my pre-trained model (saved and loaded) and receive prediction in string format.

I am using Captcha OCR from this source - https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/

Those two approaches below got me the farthest (I think) but they are still not working:

APPROACH 1:

```
model = load_model('trained_models/my_trained_model.h5', custom_objects={'CTCLayer': CTCLayer})

img_path = '/test/my_image.jpeg'

img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(200, 50))

img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
img_batch = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)

img_preprocessed = preprocess_input(img_batch)

prediction = model.predict(img_preprocessed)
```

With this approach I didn't convert image to grey scale but before it could make any troubles I receive this error:

```
ValueError: Layer ocr_model_v1 expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 200, 50, 3) dtype=float32>]
```

APPROACH 2:
This approach is pretty much copied from data preprocessing from OCR model:

```
img = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img, channels=1)
img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
img = tf.image.resize(img, [200, 50])
img_preprocessed = tf.transpose(img, perm=[1, 0, 2])

prediction = model.predict(img_preprocessed)
```

And it gives me pretty much they same error:

```
ValueError: Layer ocr_model_v1 expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 200, 1) dtype=float32>]
```

But this time it looks like image is additionally malformed.

I think this error is caused by this line in OCR:

```
# Define the model
model = keras.models.Model(
    inputs=[input_img, labels], outputs=output, name="ocr_model_v1"
)
```

Since the model is expecting two values (while training we were passing dict with image and image name (answer to captcha)). But now, I would like this model to actually predict the image so I am not able to pass answer/label.

After several hours, I was able to push this up to this moment but right now I ran out of ideas.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

/// ---------- /// EDIT /// ---------- ///

Hi! I wanted to edit my question. In the meantime I was able to pass jpeg into this model but in not so clean way. I basically copied all the code from lowest part of this tutorial - https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/

Thanks to that I am not receiving any errors but there is really a lot of code that seems redundant but I am not able to refactor it efficiently.

With this code changed:

```
prediction_model = keras.models.Model(
    trained_model.get_layer(name="image").input, trained_model.get_layer(name="dense2").output
)
```

Now I am receiving errors about wrong Shapes etc. Is it possible to somehow refactor code from section "Inference" of this tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

From the last code snippet and "Since the model is expecting two values (while training we were passing dict with image and image name (answer to captcha)). But now, I would like this model to actually predict the image so I am not able to pass answer/label." statement you have made.

you are trying to train a model that outputs the label of a Captcha image. Therefore, your model has to be a multiclass classification model [if a finite small number of image labels] or an image similarity searching dictionary learning method [if there are a very large number of classes]. However, under both model architectures you dataset format has to be in {X : Captcha image , y : related image label}.
`model = keras.model.fit(inputs=input_img, outputs=labels)`
or if in the data preprocessing step outputs in dataset object
`model = keras.model.fit(data=img_preprocessed)`
the resulting model will support both your inferencing [make predictions] methods stated above.

Comment: Hi! I am sorry, I am not sure I follow. So you are saying that "Training" section of this code - https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/ is constructed in a wrong way?

Comment: Yes. you have to train again, after updating your code base.

Comment: But if you look under section "Preprocessing" last line of code is `return {'image': img, 'label': label}`. That is single sample is a dictionary with encoded image and label converted to numbers. Isn't it the thing you are talking about?

Comment: yes. but the model has a single input variable [image] and single output variable [label]. Because if you have two input variables in the training phase, then you must have same number of input variables in evaluation, testing and inference phases.

Comment: But how would the model learn then? I thought that all models needs to have object and answer, captcha - captcha answer, animal image - cat, animal image - dog etc. Maybe I am missing some core concept. Can I please ask you to extend your answer to include more fixed code from the keras.io example?

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. FYI, the objective function in your case most probably categorical cross-entropy function do image to label mapping will training [ by a distribution estimation method]

Comment: Also, in your reference Keras code, [here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/#training) it in the right form [the second form I stated.]

Answer (score 0):

Get the prediction model by extracting layers till the output layer:

```
prediction_model = keras.models.Model(
model.input[0], model.get_layer(name="dense2").output
```

)

save this model.

```
prediction_model.save("model.keras")
```